# SQLAlchemy min/max of query with limit

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

**Hello everyone,**

I have a couple of sensors reading temperature and humidity. With SQLAlchemy I succeeded to query the last ten results of every sensor with:

```
 sensorlist = db.session.query(Sensor).order_by(Sensor.id.asc()).all()
    for sensor in sensorlist:
        readings = sensor.readings.order_by(Sensorreading.time.desc()).limit(10)
```

Now I want of the ten results the min and the max, so I can present that of every sensor. Something like:

```
<sensor 1, min temp = 23, max temp = 26, min hum = 56, max hum =74>
<sensor 2, min temp = 22, max temp = 30, min hum = 51, max hum =63>
<sensor 3, min temp = 24, max temp = 25, min hum = 62, max hum =75>
```

But I don't know how to query that with SQLAlchemy/python. For every reading I did it with this code, but then I can't get it work to limit the data before calculate min/max. If I replace .all() for .limit(10), then it just query ten sensors, instead of ten readings:

```
sensors = db.session.query(Sensor.name, db.func.min(Sensorreading.temp_value).label("temp_value_min"), db.func.max(Sensorreading.temp_value).label("temp_value_max")).outerjoin(Sensorreading, Sensor.id == Sensorreading.sensor_id).group_by(Sensor.name).all()
```

Just for some background information the models of my table:

```
class Sensor(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    sensor_type = db.Column(db.Integer)
    pin = db.Column(db.Integer)
    limit_temp_up = db.Column(db.Float)
    limit_temp_down = db.Column(db.Float)
    limit_hum_up = db.Column(db.Float)
    limit_hum_down = db.Column(db.Float)
    limit_aqua_temp_up = db.Column(db.Float)
    limit_aqua_temp_down = db.Column(db.Float)
    readings = db.relationship('Sensorreading', backref='sensor', lazy='dynamic')

class Sensorreading(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    time = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    temp_value = db.Column(db.Float)
    hum_value = db.Column(db.Float)
    aqua_temp_value = db.Column(db.Float)
    sensor_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('sensor.id'))
```

Hope someone can help. Any tip, tricks, code helps or links are welcome! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will return the entire list and you can use slicing in python list

```
sensors = db.session.query(Sensor.name, db.func.min(Sensorreading.temp_value).label("temp_value_min"), db.func.max(Sensorreading.temp_value).label("temp_value_max")).outerjoin(Sensorreading, Sensor.id == Sensorreading.sensor_id).group_by(Sensor.name).all()[:10]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think is better to use limit and offset in this case. If you return a big data set from your sql and slice the set in memory that would cause some unnecessary overhead.

This solution will return a data set with 10 items(the pagination happens in the sql side):

```
sensors = db.session.query(Sensor.name, db.func.min(Sensorreading.temp_value).label("temp_value_min"), db.func.max(Sensorreading.temp_value).label("temp_value_max")).outerjoin(Sensorreading, Sensor.id == Sensorreading.sensor_id).group_by(Sensor.name).limit(10).offset(0).all()
```

For offset you need the first item - 1. So page 1 start with item 1 you need the offset as 0. For page 2 offset will be 11 - 1 = 10.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on the database side by first creating a common table expression that ranks each row for each sensor by id, and then group by the sensor but only over the first ten rows for each sensor.

```py
with Session() as s:
    # Assign each row a number based on sensor and id.    
    cte = sa.select(
        Sensorreading.sensor_id,
        Sensorreading.temp_value,
        sa.func.row_number()
        .over(partition_by=Sensorreading.sensor_id, order_by=Sensorreading.id)
        .label('rn'),
    ).cte('cte')
    
    # Now take the max grouped by sensor name, but only for 
    # the first ten rows for each sensor.
    q = ( 
        sa.select(Sensor.name, sa.func.max(cte.c.temp_value))
        .join(cte, Sensor.id == cte.c.sensor_id)
        .where(cte.c.rn <= 10)
        .group_by(Sensor.name)
        .order_by(Sensor.name)
    )
 
    res = s.execute(q)
    for row in res:
        print(row)
```

This example uses standard SQLAlchemy; it can be mostly converted to Flask-SQLAlchemy by removing the `with` line, changing `s` to `db.session` and converting `sa.` to `db.`.